# OperationBehaviorAttribute error when running svcutil.exe on WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception

I'm getting a very strange error when I try to run svcutil.exe on a WCF service.

> "OperationBehaviorAttribute can only go on the service class"
>
> [InvalidOperationException]: OperationBehaviorAttribute can only go on the service class, it cannot be put on the ServiceContract interface. Method 'EditProduct' on type 'IProductWCF' violates this."

I have pasted my code below and if anybody can shed any light on this, I'd really appreciate it.

I should point out that it works on every method except "EditOpportunityProductTypes"

My Interface:

```
namespace ProductWCF
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IProductWCF
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string SayHello(AppointmentFeedback objAppointmentFeedback);

        [OperationContract]
        Boolean CreateAppointmentFeedback(AppointmentFeedback objAppointmentFeedback);

        [OperationContract]
        List<ExpiringContractType> GetOpportunityProductTypes(int opportunityId);

        [OperationBehavior]
        Boolean EditOpportunityProductTypes(List<ExpiringContractType> lstExpiringContractTypes, int opportunityId);
    }
}
```

My Service:

```
namespace ProductWCF
{
    public class Service : IProductWCF
    {
        [OperationBehavior]
        public string SayHello(AppointmentFeedback objAppointmentFeedback)
        {
            return objAppointmentFeedback.Notes;
        }

        [OperationBehavior]
        public Boolean CreateAppointmentFeedback(AppointmentFeedback objAppointmentFeedback)
        {    
            ProductData.CRM.Objects.AppointmentFeedback objNewAppointmentFeedback = new AppointmentFeedback();    
            if (objNewAppointmentFeedback.Insert(objAppointmentFeedback.AppointmentId, objAppointmentFeedback.StarId, objAppointmentFeedback.AppointmentStatusId, objAppointmentFeedback.Notes, objAppointmentFeedback.Creator, objAppointmentFeedback.AttendeeName) > 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        [OperationBehavior]
        public List<ExpiringContractType> GetOpportunityProductTypes(int opportunityId)
        {    
            return OpportunityProductTypeMethods.GetOpportunityConnectionTypes(opportunityId);
                      
        }

        [OperationBehavior]
        public Boolean EditOpportunityProductTypes(List<ExpiringContractType> lstExpiringContractTypes, int opportunityId)
        {
            return ProductData.CRM.Objects.OpportunityProductTypeMethods.UpdateOpportunityConnectionTypes(lstExpiringContractTypes, opportunityId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have decorated the `EditOpportunityProductTypes` method in the *interface* with the `OperationBehavior` attribute:

```
 [OperationBehavior]
 Boolean EditOpportunityProductTypes(List lstExpiringContractTypes, int opportunityId);
```

You probably meant to use `OperationContract` there:

```
 [OperationContract]
 Boolean EditOpportunityProductTypes(List lstExpiringContractTypes, int opportunityId);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Is there any reason the other methods work and the only one that doesn't is EditOpportunityProductTypes?

Comment: @Nick: the other method are in the interface decorated with `OperationContract` as they should, so there is no problem with them.

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that! Thank you :)